# XSL Variable passed to JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, html, xslt, innerhtml, xsl-variable

I've seen that similar questions were asked, but none helped.

I have a variable, called '**var**':

```
<xsl:variable name="var">
  val
</xsl:variable>
```

And I want to use it as such:

```
<a onclick=
  "
    this.innerHTML = 'my var = ??? '/>;
  "
>
  click-Me
</a>
```

The problem: Replace ??? with **var**'s value.

I've tried setting `{$var}` as well as `<xsl:value-of select="$var"/>`, but the latest won't work since there are three nested brackets.

Comment: In what way do you "have" this variable `var`?

Comment: It's hidden data of a table cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be the following.  First I would make a hidden div to hold the content of the xsl var:

```
<div style="display:none" id="content-div">
     <xsl:value-of select="$var"/>
</div>
```

Then bind a click event (not inline) to the link as follows:

```
<a id="some-link">
  click-Me
</a>

<script>
     document.getElementById('some-link').onclick = function(){
          this.innerHTML = document.getElementById('content-div').innerHTML;
     };
</script>
```